# Wake on LAN option in BIOS

Tags: bios, network-adapter, wake-on-lan

In the BIOS option for many PCs I've looked at- you typically see these 3 options (among others) which you can enable/disable independently:

- Power On By External Modems
- Power On By PCI Devices
- Power On By PCIE Devices

In my experience- WoL only functions with the on-board NIC when the 3rd option "....PCIe devices" is enabled.

It would make more sense to me if it said "Power On By on-board Ethernet" or something equivalent.

My question: why would an on-board network card (not an add-on card plugged into a PCIe slot) have anything to do with the PCIe option in the BIOS?

Is there some link between PCIe and the onboard NIC on some PCs, or was this just an arbitrary BIOS design decision? I've seen this on various different models of PC, from different manufacturers. Sorry I don't have specifics right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All on-board devices are in fact attached via PCI or PCI express. Rather than using a physical peripheral slot, they are instead hard-wired PCI/PCI-E devices -- directly to your motherboard's north-bridge chipset (PCI-E) or south-bridge chipset (PCI).

The only difference between an on-board device and a peripheral card is that on-board devices are not removable (without some guru level of soldering skills of course).

Comment: Wow so I guess if they use either PCI or PCIe, the only way to know which option applies to WoL on any given PC model is trial and error (they don't even say in the manual) or just enabling both options.

I was hoping there was some general rule which applies to all situations so I could just enable one option in the BIOS each time instead of a bunch of options.

Comment: Generally motherboards these days have all of their on-board devices connected via PCI-E. Classic PCI is rarely used these days, and often only via the physical slot. If your motherboard has a USB 1.1 controller, serial COM ports, or parallel LPT ports they will likely use PCI too.The block diagram in your motherboard manual will certainly show you how your on-board devices are connected. Mine is from 2010, and only PS/2 ports, IEEE 1394 ports, and the floppy disk drive use the PCI bus. Everything else is PCI-E.

Comment: Ok I'll go for PCIe in future then- but I always double check it's working before I leave because I need to know I can rely on it to some extent. Thanks for the info

Comment: No problem. If in doubt, motherboard block diagrams in the manuals usually show you very clearly.